# Please allow new users to see Close Vote feedback

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

From a comment at [How do I install SSL on Wampserver 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343918/how-do-i-install-ssl-on-wampserver-3#comment67942086_40343918):

> lately I have received a lot of down votes on my posts, but I don't know why... If you downvote, could you please explain why?

While the user asked specifically about downvotes, he's speaking to a bigger problem on Stack Overflow. The bigger problem is lack of feedback for new users.

Its not clear to me why new users are denied feedback like Close Vote reasons. In the bigger picture, I think its a mistake that does more harm than good. I think its a mistake because users don't receive feedback and don't correct behavior, so they ask more ill-suited questions.

Please allow new users, who often don't have the required number of points, to see Close Vote feedback.

Comment: Related proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285951/262399

Comment: I think something like [Clippy](http://imgur.com/a/xaNxx) could be very helpful in general to provide feedback of what is going on, explaining how to do something or showing what exactly you can do. Clippy would be automatically activated and above a certain reputation it will disable itself. You could still turn it manually on again. Clippy could always pop up when you do something or when something happens, as example: "Hey, it seems like you just got a close vote this means ... now you should do ... ".

Comment: Couldn't this be confusing for a new user if they don't realise that most close votes need several users to agree before the question is actually closed (Mjolnir not withstanding). A single close vote does not necessarily mean the question is going to be closed. If the question is closed, the user gets an explanation with links to how to fix the question and vote to reopen.

Comment: @Steve While it is true that it needs multiple people to close a question I think that a close vote and the chosen reason with it many times also relate with downvotes or not getting any answers. So letting the user know with what reason the question is getting closed could help the OP to edit and improve his question earlier while it is still "new" in the question list.

Comment: @Steve That is a potential issue. Would changing the wording so that the rather esoteric concept of "close vote" is not mentioned, as in "Another user has evaluated your question as unclear. Consider editing it so that etc.", help? Or would that be too misleading?

Comment: @Rizier123 my point is someone could choose any option for a close vote even if it's not relevant. If it's actually a good question the vote will age away with no action. Imagine if you posted a question and got told someone thinks it's spam, or opinion based when it's not. If you didn't know about the multiple votes you might be even further confused as to why it's happening.

Comment: @duplode I'm not sure it's a wording problem. The whole point of requiring multiple close votes is to ensure there is consensus before taking action.

Comment: @Steve A good point. Maybe this can be solved so that the reason only gets shown to the OP when 2 or 3 users have chosen the same reason. So the OP still would know about the closing process before it is closed.

Comment: @Steve A good point indeed. One consequence is that there shouldn't be a strongly worded automatic message, as it is always possible that one close vote (or more) might be misguided.

Comment: Saying that this post is a bug report doesn't change the meat of the post, which appears to be a feature request.  Just because you believe the intended function is a bug, doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Daedalus - perhaps you are not familiar with policy and procedures. The bug report created an actionable item for Stack Overflow. The site has to take action. There action can be "no action/won't fix". That's clearly different than the endless debate from anyone who has an opinion.

Comment: That's not how that works.  You don't just mis-tag feature requests as bug reports because you think it will result in increased attention from developers.  The bug tag is for bugs with existing features, not for feature requests.

Comment: I support this feature request.  I don't support this bug.

Comment: @jww I guess I'm not familiar with policy; please cite the official policy for the bug tag, stating it can be used for feature requests, so that I may educate myself.  I've checked the [meta-tag:bug] tag info, and it says nothing of the sort.

Comment: @Daedalus - like I said, you would need to be familiar with Policy and Procedure, Change Control, etc. If your understanding of the topics only extend to a Stack Exchange tag, there's not much to discuss.

Comment: @jww I'm not asking to discuss it.  I'm asking you to cite the document.  Saying that X is Y doesn't really cut it here.  Policy means officially sanctioned procedures.  In this case, the SE network is what determines what is policy and what isn't; for there to be a policy, means there to be a document of some sort detailing this policy.  So please cite it.